# Insertion Sort for student database

Tags: c

I am currently attempting at using an insertion sort for my "grades.csv" file(excel). I placed the grades.csv into an string array called char line[]. Inside the file contains: StudentID, Exam1, Exam2, Exam3 and Grade. I placed the studentID and grade into two string arrays.

The program is only required to sort studentID. However, whenever a studentID gets moved, the grade for that studentID also gets moved, hence having the grades string in the insertion sort. If sort is successful, the program should print out the index, studentID and grade.

I was successful in reading the data from the file and printed it out, however, my insertion sort does not seem to work properly, since nothing gets printed out when called:

```
//Declaration:
void insertionSort(char listID[],
                   char grades[],
                     int length);
//call
int main(void)
{
FILE* f = fopen("grades.csv", "r");
if (f == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error opening file test.dat.");
        exit(1);
}
///////
char line[70];
int size = strlen(line);
char studentID[7];
char grade[2];
char exam1[3];
char exam2[3];
char exam3[3];
int num;

printf("\t+---------+-------+-------+-------+------+\n");
printf("\t| Student | Exam1 | Exam2 | Exam3 | Grade|\n");
printf("\t+---------+-------+------+-------+-------+\n");


while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), f) != NULL){
        sscanf(line,  
                "%25[0123456789], %6[0123456789], %2[^,], %2[^,],%2[^,],%[ ABCD]",
                studentID, exam1, exam2, exam3, grade);

printf("\t| %s  | %+4s  | %+4s  | %+4s  | %+4s \n ",
studentID, exam1, exam2, exam3, grade);




printf("\t+---------+-------+------+-------+------+\n");

for(int j=0; j<size; j++;)
{
insertionSort(studentID, grade, size-1);


printf( "\t %d |  %s | %s\n", j, studentID, grade);
}

void insertionSort(char listID[], char grades[], int length)
{ 
        int walk;
        char key, key1;
        bool located;
        int current;
   for (current = 1; current <= length; current++)
   {
       located = false;
       key = listID[current];
       key1= grades[current];


       for (walk = current - 1; walk >= 0 && !located;)
       {
        if (key < listID[walk])
        {
           listID[walk+1] = listID[current];
           grades[walk+1] = grades[current];
           walk--;
        }
        else
        located =  true; 
       listID[walk+1] = key;
       grades[walk+1] = key1;
   }
}
}
```

Comment: `char line[70]; int size = strlen(line);`. That' incorrect. `line` is unitialised so calling `strlen` on it results in Undefined Behaviour. Suggest you use a debugger to help you debug your program.

Comment: would it be `sizeof(line)` instead of `strlen` ? @kaylum